# How does the memory allocation happen when I declare a char pointer and then later assign a string constant to it?

Tags: c, char, heap-memory

Well I have seen declarations like

```
char strng[20]="";
strcpy(strng,"Some_String");
```

Here it is well understood that when I declare `strng[20]`, i am reserving 20 memory locations(bytes) for this character array so I can copy any string to it which is almost 20 characters long.

Also, a declaration like

```
char *strng;
strng=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*n);
```

Which will create a character pointer(2 bytes), and then memory is allocated via`malloc`  and the base address of the allocated memory is assigned to `strng`. Here,`n` bytes will be allocated.

But, I have seen declarations like

```
char *srtng;
strng="Some_Very_Long_Text";
```

So, How is memory being allocated in this case? Here I am declaring a char pointer(2 bytes) then assigning a string to it. If the size of this string is`n`, then how and where is this string stored? my pointer only holds its base address. when is memory allocated and how? I am not even using `malloc` here.

Comment: The linked page's answers might be too technical because they mostly focus on segments and what the standards say. I suggest that you think about it this way: The character array is within "load-time" memory. You are just assigning a pointer to it. Load-time memory (however the compiler&OS are implementing it) already exists at the time your program starts (and is filled with the appropriate data). It may be implemented this way: you click on an executable file, the OS copies the exe (including the char-array) into RAM, it does further setup, then starts the program, ..., you assign a pointer.